# MVC 4 TextBoxFor and others automatically calling HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Problem**

I'm trying to implement a HTML5/jQuery mock-up in MVC and am running into an issue I've never encountered before; it appears using Html.TextBoxFor, Html.PasswordFor and others all automatically encode any HTML attributes that are passed.

**Example**

Take the following line for example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pin, new { data_regexp="<\\d{4}>" })
```

This code would be used to validate a PIN number on a credit card and I need to use the data-regexp pattern to pass the appropriate regular expression. I would expect the output to be the following:

```
<input data-regexp="<\d{4}>" id="Pin" type="text" />
```

Instead, it appears to be calling HtmlAttributeEncode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf.aspx) from within the built in extension, resulting in the following ***encoded*** output:

```
<input data-regexp="&lt;\d{4}>" id="Pin" type="text" />
```

**Desired Solution Note**

Do I have any other option than to write my own extensions? Using other forms of validation isn't an option and this example is just to show the issue at hand - I have several other examples where I need the raw HTML printed, not an encoded version.

*Edit:
Using Html.Raw or HttpUtility.Decode have no impact. The encoding occurs after any of these are applied.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I added the following class:

```
namespace MyProjectName.Extensions
{
    public class HtmlAttributeNoEncoding : HttpEncoder
    {
        protected override void HtmlAttributeEncode(string value, TextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write(value);
        }
    }
}
```

And modified my web config:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" encoderType="MyProjectName.Extensions.HtmlAttributeNoEncoding"/>
    ... 
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this custom HTMLHelper extension:

Custom HtmlHelper Extensions:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace MvcApplication.Extensions
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes, object dataAttribute)
        {
            MvcHtmlString textBoxFor = InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(htmlHelper, expression, htmlAttributes);

            string stringDataAttributes = string.Empty;
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(dataAttribute))
            {
                stringDataAttributes+= string.Format("data-{0}=\"{1}\" ", property.Name, property.GetValue(dataAttribute));
            }

            string textBoxForText = textBoxFor.ToHtmlString();
            string textBoxWithData = textBoxForText.Insert(textBoxForText.IndexOf("/>"), stringDataAttributes);

            return htmlHelper.Raw(textBoxWithData);
        }
    }
}
```

cshtml:

```
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(m => m.Pin, null, new { regexp = "<\\d{5}>" })
```

Result:

```
<input id="Pin" name="Pin" type="text" value="" data-regexp="<\d{5}>" />
```

Comment: I really appreciate that! I was considering writing my own extensions, but it's looking like I'm going to have to do it for just about every one that's already built in. If I can't find any other way around it, this is definitely the route I'll take.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you use a data annotation on the model.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{4}", ErrorMessage="4 digit PIN required")]
public string Pin { get; set; }
```

You can then just use the TextboxFor without passing extra attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pin)
```

This returns html as:

```
data-val-regex="4 digit PIN required" data-val-regex-pattern="\d{4}"
```

Comment: This definitely would work if I could change the validation library, but the example I gave is for more than just validation (it's just one of a handful of issues I'm having with the encoding). I'm looking for something more general, namely how do I get the entire HtmlAttributes block to not be encoded?

Comment: Okay, sorry! I think you'd need to look at custom extensions for that.